# help with mental issues

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Can "with" be omitted in the following?

> Interacting with a pet can help **with** many mental issues.

Comment: It wouldn't sound quite right. It's not the mental issues that are being helped, but the patient's attempts to cope with them.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. Do you mean the "with" must be there?

Comment: Yes - omitting _with_ wouldn't sound right.